# Первые два оператора "case 1" вылетают друг за другом. Как это исправить?

Tags: java

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
switch (choice)
{
    case 1 : 
        System.out.println("Введите имя : "); bname = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите номер участка : "); bnumZone = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите номер машины : "); bcar = scan.nextLine();
        Zone Misha = new Zone(bname, bnumZone, bcar);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); // !!!
switch (choice)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Никита Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.